# Serial string not being read consistantly

Tags: serial, c

If I send the following string to the rpi

```
echo "#q10"  > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Why does the whole string not get read each time its sent?
This is the app output

[image: See code below]

The code is as follows. I am using the serial wiring library from Gordons project

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd;

struct obj_Properties
{
char *one;
char *two;
char *three;
char *four;
};

int main()
{
if ((fd = serialOpen("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)) < 0)
{
 return 1;
}

for(;;){
while (serialDataAvail (fd))
 {
 struct obj_Properties prop;
 prop.one = serialGetchar(fd);
 prop.two = serialGetchar(fd);
 prop.three = serialGetchar(fd);
 prop.four = serialGetchar(fd);
 printf ("%c %c %c %c\n", prop.one, prop.two, prop.three, prop.four);

 fflush (stdout) ;

}
usleep(10000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the first byte is available you read four bytes.  The first byte being ready does not imply all four bytes (plus line feed) have been received.

Comment: I added an extra char in the code and one less in the string and it is working. It seems obvious now but even though I used differing string sizes I never tested for 2 extra chars - thanks..